# Travis CI + Docker + Ubuntu для тестирования сборки библиотеки

Tags: github, docker, docker-compose, travis

Здравствуйте!

У меня в GitHub есть проект, который я хочу тестировать на разных компиляторах.
Но проблема в том, что Travis CI предлагает устаревший дистрибутив ubuntu trusty, а соответственно и все устаревшее окружение. Поэтому на помощь приходит только **docker**. С ним я не знаком.

**Для моих целей необходимо:**

```
cmake 3.0+
make
openssl (libssl-dev 1.1.0a+)
g++ 4.9.2
g++ 5
g++ 6
clang++ 3.7
clang++ 3.8
clang++ 3.9
```

В качестве ОС, я считаю, достаточно **ubuntu 16.10**.

На сегодняшний момент, единственное, что я научился делать, это устанавливать в Travis CI последние версии docker-engine и docker-compose (я так понимаю, он и нужен для запуска сразу нескольких контейнеров с разным environment).

**Это делается следующим образом:**

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: cpp

   install:
     - curl -sSL "https://get.docker.com/gpg" | sudo -E apt-key add -
     - echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
     - sudo apt-get update -q
     - sudo apt-get install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" --force-yes -y docker-engine
     - docker --version

     - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.11.1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
     - chmod +x docker-compose
     - sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin
     - docker-compose --version
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно для таких нужд организовать файл **.travis.yml** и как в нем работать с **docker**?

Спасибо!

Comment: в документации по Travis CI написано как надо использовать докер https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/

Comment: На том сайте ничего не сказано о том, что мне нужно. Там используется какое-то специфическое применение docker.

Comment: вам нужно внутри докер-контейнера запустить сборку вашей библиотеки с определенными зависимостями и прогнать в ней тесты? я правильно понял?

Comment: Да. Но при этом мне это надо сделать с 6 разными компиляторами.

Comment: тогда там то, что вам нужно описано. хотя если я все правильно понимаю, то есть все же возможность поставить нужные версии без докера.